# Create a simple output textbox in python

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I'm doing a program where I'm simulating a tennis match. At the moment I'm printing the result in the shell as follows:

```
15 - 0
30 - 0
40 - 0
40 - 15
40 - 30
game: B Borg
0 - 15
0 - 30
15 - 30
etc....
```

How do I create a simple textbox that would be updated every time the results are updated in my code?

I have tried different codes but whenever the textbox are created it gets stuck in the mainloop just showing 15 - 0...

I need to be able to send 2 variables to the gui function every time the score changes.

```
 from tkinter import *
   root = Tk()
   var = StringVar()
   l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
   l.pack()
   root.update_idletasks()

   def gui(player1_points, player2_points): 
           var.set(player1_points,"-" ,player2_points)
```

Comment: I dont understand how your `gui` function is called? where does player1_points and player2_points come from? Can you provide more compete example, or some dummy (but working) version of it?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you should call `tk.mainloop()` at some point, rather than `tk.update_idletasks()`. Your code will need several more changes to work properly, though.

[Here's a nice Tkinter example](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php) which should bring you very close to what you want (scroll down to the last section labelled "Dynamical Content in a Label").

Comment: Is it possible to do without the main loop? I will still be using the shell for all user input (i.e choosing players) and to print out player lists etc. and don't want to get "stuck" in the mainloop of the GUI. Is it possible to create a GUI that just receives values continuously, prints them and then jumps back into the "normal" code without the GUI closing down. Just a print function that prints to the GUI instead of to the shell and dont actually go into a mainloop in the GUI? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!!

```
def print_funk(player1_points, player2_point):
        points_pl_1 = "0"
        points_pl_2 = "0"
        if player1_points <=3 and player2_points <=3:
          if player1_points == 0:
            points_pl_1 =  "0"
          if player1_points == 1:
            points_pl_1 =  "15"
          if player1_points == 2:
            points_pl_1 =  "30"
          if player1_points == 3:
            points_pl_1 =  "40"

          if player2_points == 0:
            points_pl_2 =  "0"
          if player2_points == 1:
            points_pl_2 =  "15"
          if player2_points == 2:
            points_pl_2 =  "30"
          if player2_points == 3:
            points_pl_2 =  "40"
          #print (points_pl_1, "-", points_pl_2)
           gui(points_pl_1, points_pl_2):
```

This is a print funktion that receives values "live" from another function with a bit of time delay. What I want is to instead of printing the result in the shell I would like to print the result in a GUI to make it look more like a "real" tennis game. So every time `def print_funk(player1_points, player2_point):` is called I want to call the GUI function and print the result there instead. i.e call `gui(points_pl_1, points_pl_2):`